# Enable / Disable all controls on view/page in asp.net mvc based on role or access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a asp.net mvc 4 website. 
Requirement is -

- There are roles given for each user for this site.
- Also there is table specifying which all tabs/views a role can have access to.
- Based on user's role & view/page he/she is visiting, disable or enable all controls on that view/page.
  Eg.
- User with Account role don't have access to Search & View page. For this user these 2 pages should show all controls in disabled state.
- User with Admin role have access to Search & View page. For this user these 2 pages should show all controls in enabled state.

Any solution for this?

Comment: What have you already tried? This has to be one of the top 10 most googled topics of ASP.NET MVC ... Did you google and search stack overflow before posting? What part of this are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: I done some search. Problem is with how to enable or disable all controls on page. Eg. there is grid displayed along with 8-10 filtering conditions mixed with text boxes & combos. Hope this is clear.

Comment: hi, you got any solution for this?